# How do i check if the steam account is a developer account with existing developed games on Steam?

Tags: steam, steam-web-api, steamworks-api

I have been reading through the Steam API but I can't seem to find anything that would allow me to check if the steam user is a developer account and also to check which games have been developed by the developer account.

What I am trying to achieve is to authenticate users using OpenID and then check if user a steamworks developer and also to check for developed games.

Answer (score 0):

> Steam can act as an OpenID provider. This allows your application to authenticate a **user's SteamID** without requiring them to enter their Steam username or password on your site (which would be a violation of the API Terms of Use.)

You can't access this kind of data with Steam API.

Only **Publisher** can list his Games/Apps using his own Publisher's API Key.

> https://lab.xpaw.me/steam_api_documentation.html#ISteamUser_GetPublisherAppOwnership_v2
>   https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/webapi/ISteamUser#GetPublisherAppOwnership

Correct me if I'm wrong.

Check this link: https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/SteamID
Maybe with SteamID you will be able to detect if someone have Developer account.